# How to change the encoding of PCollection data into ASCII while writing data into a file through dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I want to use ASCII coder in dataflow while writing data into a file on GCS. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: You should edit your question with what you have tried and what specific problem you have. Open-ended questions are unlikely to get any helpful answers.

Comment: @Prayag which language do you use?

Comment: Please show some pipeline code, and what the output looks like (and what you'd like it to look like)